# php 5.3.10 Fatal Error NOT being thrown when using typehinting

Tags: php, type-hinting

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$import_manager->import_story('TEST');

public function import_story(ArchiveArticle $article)
{
    var_dump($article);
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "TEST"
```

Why isn't a fatal error being thrown?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the corresponding method?